# Find matrix exponential $e^{A+B}$ when $A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that the coefficient of $A^{m-l}B^l$ in $e^{A+B}=1+\frac{A+B}{1!}+\frac{(A+B)^2}{2!}+$... is $\frac{1}{l!(m-l)!}$, the formula for choosing $l$ things from a set of $m$ things,  when $A=B$.

This is a problem from Naive Lie Theory, but its really just a linear algebra question.

Comment: What is $l$? What is $m$?

Comment: Are $A,B$ matrices? If so $e^A$ is a matrix. So what's $\frac {1}{l!(m-l)!}$?

Comment: It's still not clear. Please copy the whole problem.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD my mistake, made a typo, its about the coefficient

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ and $B$ commute, the only place $A^{m-l} B^l$ appears in the expansion of the exponential is in $(A+B)^m/m!$, where the terms have total degree $m$ in $A$ and $B$.  By the binomial theorem, the coefficient of $A^{m-l} B^l$ in $(A+B)^m$ is ${m \choose l} = \frac{m!}{(m-l)!\; l!}$, and dividing by $m!$ you get $1/((m-l)!\; l!)$.